# Xcode delete a line on top of an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have an image in a UIView.
On top of it I have drawn a blue, horizontal line with:

```
UIView *lineViewHorizon = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, pageTopMargin+inthorizon, self.view.bounds.size.width, 2)];
lineViewHorizon.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:lineViewHorizon];
```

How do I remove this line so the picture appears without the line in front of it.
Clearly using clearColor does nothing :-)

Do I need to delete the layer and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[lineViewHorizon removeFromSuperview]
```